# PHP issues on include

Tags: php

I'm currently loading an include file `config.php` into a php page. This file contains many strings, variables and alike. There is a secondary file that I would like to include on the page with the site menu and a few other things.

This file contains the code below which does not work if loaded in the page as an include. It does work if I insert the file directly on the page.

Can someone help me figure out what's wrong with this?

```
<?php

    foreach ($page as $key => $item) 
        if ($page[$key][4] == basename(__DIR__)) 
            echo $page[$key][0] . " - " . $company_name;

?>
```

File Structure:

- about/index.php (this is the webpage I'm loading the files into)
- includes/omniPro/head-elements.php (This is the file containing the peace of code)

I'm including this file in the about/index.php with the following syntax:

```
<?php include '../includes/omniPro/head-elements.php'; ?>
```

When I look at the rendered HTML page it shows the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8888/css/colors.php?color=" type="text/css" />
```

and it was supposed to render this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8888/css/colors.php?color=FCC444" type="text/css" />
```

It loads the included file with the static content but it doesn't render the code itself, which is a color number FCC444 right after color="

If I insert this code directly on the page, it works just fine. Here's the code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="
<?php 
    echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; 
?>
/css/colors.php?color=
<?php 

    if($color {main} == '') {
        foreach ($page as $key => $item) 
            if ($page[$key][4] == basename(__DIR__)) 
                echo $page[$key][2];} 
            else 
                echo $color {main};

?>
" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: How do you include the file? What is your folder structure ?

Comment: /includes/base/config.php (This is the file containing all the variables and strings). the other file containing this peace of code is located at the same directory /includes/base/head.php. the page where I'm including this file is /about/index.php. The include syntax does not seem to be the problem as I have tried other codes and it worked just fine. It looks like this: <?php include '../../includes/omniPro/head-elements.php'; ?>

Comment: ^ Please update your question with the file where you include the file shown above and also add your folder structure into your question where the files which you work with are

Comment: Question updated as per your request. Thanks for your help.